# Run a console application ( which internally invokes powershell scripts) an azure web job

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a console application that among other tasks, invokes a powershell script. I would like to run this from a web job on a schedule.

a) I was able to publish my console application to a web job and I had good luck with running this. However, had to choose the on demand option and have to trigger it manually.

b) I packaged the output of my project in a zip and uploaded it to a new webjob (which i was able to schedule!!) However, this time the web job ran but failed to load and run the powershell scripts. It complains with the following error: (Not sure how I can control execution policies)
System.Management.Automation.PSSecurityException: File D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\ScheduledTenantExpiryMonitor\i2eejhup.fkj\WebJobzip\GetExpirationScript.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170. ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException:

Can someone help me figure this out? The end goal is to run my job successfully in a scheduled fashion.

Comment: you can run powershell script as a job, dont you ?

Answer (score 0):

To invoke the powershell file directly, you could take the suggestions of @Thomas.

[Running Powershell Web Jobs on Azure websites](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nicktrog/2014/01/22/running-powershell-web-jobs-on-azure-websites/)

If you did want to invoke powershell command with Console Application, you could do it with Powshell .NET SDK. It can run powershell command with .NET Console Application in WebJobs. Here are the detail steps.

1. Install System.Management.Automation dll using NuGet.
2. Run powershell scripts using following method.

```
private static string RunScript(string scripts)
{
    // create Powershell runspace
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    // open it
    runspace.Open();
    // create a pipeline and feed it the script text 
    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scripts);
    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");
    //execute the script
    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
    //close the runspace
    runspace.Close();
    // convert the script result into a single string
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }
    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

3. Test upper method using following code. command.ps1 file contains Get-Process command.

```
string fileName = "command.ps1";
string scriptText = File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + fileName);
Console.Write(scriptText);
```

Here is the output of Get-Process command in WebJob.

[image]